# Run ansible-playbook from localhost, and using vars from hosts file

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

Let's say that I want to run something locally. but I want to use the vars from the hosts file, so basically - I want to do for each line something locally.

In this example, I want to use ec2_tag from ansible.

hosts file for ansible playbook run:

`[any]
 123.123.123.123 region=eu-region ec2_instance_id=x-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
 123.123.123.124 region=eu-region ec2_instance_id=x-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

ansible-playbook:

```
- name: something
  hosts: any
  tasks:

  - name: test
    ec2_tag:
      region: "{{ region }}"
      resource: "{{ ec2_instance_id }}""
      state: list
    register: ec2_tags

  - debug: msg={{ ec2_tags }}
```

How can i loop localy on `[any]` vars? let's say get `region`?

Answer (score 1):

It's running now with `local_action` and taking the vars from the hosts file.

```
- name: something
  hosts: any
  tasks:

  - name: test
    local_action: ec2_tag region={{ region }} resource={{ ec2_instance_id }} state=list
    register: ec2_tags
  - debug: msg={{ ec2_tags }}
```